# Can an Android heads up notification be shown more than one time without user cancel?

Tags: android, notifications, heads-up-notifications

My app targets:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 25
```

I am able to display a heads-up notification with this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
((NotificationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
            .notify(9999, notificationBuilder.build());
```

When the app tries to display another heads-up notification with the same ID but a different message, the notification is updated but is not shown as a new heads-up notification.  The notification is not displayed again over top of the app.

Is it possible to show a heads-up notification with the same ID twice without the user cancelling the first notification?

Comment: why not just cancel the notification before showing the new one?

Comment: I tried that and am getting weird behavior.  The notification icon disappears, and then reappears with the new message, but does not show heads-up!  I tried .cancel() with the ID and also .cancelAll()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [setOnlyAlertOnce()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean)) method is what you are looking for.